# Create folders alphabetically

Tags: linux, debian

How can I create every folder (A-Z) in Alphabet with the help of a shell script in Linux?

I want to have the following folder structure (for illustration):

```
/mnt/ext_hdd/A
/mnt/ext_hdd/B
/mnt/ext_hdd/C
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple [brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace):

```
mkdir -p /mnt/ext_hdd/{A..Z}
```

If you want all possible combinations, you could of course do `{A..Z}{A..Z}` and so on. If you want to test it, add an `echo` before the whole command.